# AndEngine Game Loop. Where is it?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-engine

I have experience programming games with Cocos2d and Box2d. Now I'm playing around with AndEngine and I'm a bit lost. This might sound like a dumb question, but where is the game loop for AndEngine? Where is the update() function which is normally found on other engines? I've gone through examples and I just can't find it. I saw this example http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/where-is-the-game-loop-t12.html
but it was not much help.

If you can shed some light into this, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: I read the answer in your link as "There is no game loop". But each object has some kind of event handler so you would have to do the update() per game object.

Comment: The answer provided by @user1419184 is a correct answer for your question, OP. Please accept it.

Answer (score 9):

//An easy way  is to create the game loop on the onLoadScene method

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {     
            Scene scene = new Scene();                     
            scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {                    
                public void reset() {        
                }             
                public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    //HERE IS THE GAME LOOP
                }
            });
            return scene;
}
```

Comment: Note, in AndEngine-AnchorCenter, based on OpenGL2.0, the method `registerUpdateHandler(...)` can also be called inside `onCreateScene()`. The game loop will likewise be in the `onUpdate(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for [Engine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/engine/Engine.java).

See:

- [`UpdateThread`](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/engine/Engine.java#L779)
- [`Engine.onTickUpdate()`](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/engine/Engine.java#L537)

Comment: Gedankenexperiment: Compared to `Engine`, the two subclasses contain almost no code. What design change could you imagine to get rid of the subclasses? Extend `EngineOptions` to support setting the update behaviour? Delegation?

Comment: I won't use delegation, since Engine is not interface. If i really want to get rid of subclasses, then i either use Strategy pattern, or just switch in update method based on EngineOptions.UPDATE_STRATEGY as you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement the interface IUpdateHandler in your Activity class:

```
public class YourActivityClass extends BaseGameActivity implements IUpdateHandler
{
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
    {
        //Game loop
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() 
    {   
    }
}
```

And register the update handler:

```
mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(this);
```