# Where is the Game loop in andengine when you are using the box2D extention?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-loop

Where is the Game loop in andengine when you are using the box2D extention? Without the box2d Extension the game loop is found using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863811/andengine-game-loop-where-is-it) method but when you use the box2d extension that method doesnt work because with the physics you need to go 
`scene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);`

So where can I find the game loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops! It can be found exactly by using the link in the question. Turns out the problem was actually that the app was not re installing. I was just having a bad day.